# Versions. "Is not a working copy"

Tags: svn, mamp, versions

A little background first:

I'm a designer/developer and decided to use subversion for a personal project. I'm the only one working on this project. I've setup a Beanstalk account and installed Versions on Mac. Locally I have MySQL and PHP running through MAMP. What I want to do is develop locally and push code into Beanstalk. I'm not planning on deploying from Beanstalk to my live server at this moment.

In Beanstalk I created a repository and imported all my code. I then installed Versions and added a bookmark to the Beanstalk repository. So far so good. Next I guess (this is a wild guess) I need to add a so called 'working copy bookmark' so that Versions can watch my local copy for changes and commit it to my Beanstalk repository.

Problem:
When I click 'Create working copy bookmark' in Versions and I select a folder on my computer I get the error:

'/Applications/MAMP/www_mydomain' is not a working copy'

I have no clue what that means and now I'm stuck. How can I tell Versions to keep track of changes of a local folder?

Comment: This is way outside the scope of your question, but I used to use Versions and was frustrated by it's strange terminology and ways.  Now, since I'm almost always running Parallels with a Windows O/S simultaneously, I just use TortoiseSVN and point it to my Mac source code.   I don't think anybody is ever going to catch up to TSVN for convenience and maturity as a Subversion client.

Just a thought.

Comment: I had the same issue with Versions- which is why I didn't purchase it after the trial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Not a working copy' means it is not in sync with the SVN and was either not checked out, or is a file that is not a part of the repository (in which case it needs to be Added to Working Copy).

I am not familiar with Versions, but with Subversion I typically start a project by Checking Out from the repository. This tracks changes on your end and makes it a 'working copy' of the repository.

Do you have an option to Check Out from the repository? Try to do it to a new folder and see what happens.

Comment: Yes I can check out my repository. But then my local code will be overwritten by the code that I imported into Beanstalk, right?

Comment: Yes, thats why I said to use a new folder. If you imported all your code into the repo, and haven't made any changes since then, you aren't going to lose any work. Importing into a SVN creates files on the SVN, but does not create a sync with your local copy.

Comment: Thx, it solved my problem! But I think this is very confusing process. But anyway, it's solved now.

Comment: Yeah, code versioning can be a lot to grasp at first. It will become second nature after a while of using it.

Comment: What is your setup? Theoretically nothing is broken- you can checkout from a repo as many times as you want. Is there a specific error you are getting?